# Unable to use Raphaël library

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am having a problem in using Raphaël library. Im getting following error

'R._g.doc.body' is null or not an object

i just used following code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="raphael.js"></script>
<script>
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I used IE8 for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `<body></body>`n and put your script in the `body` rather than `head`

try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="raphael.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you declared your script in the body?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but given your code and what the error message says, I'd say you need to have a `<body></body>` tag in your document.

Not sure if that is an IE8 thing. I put together your example in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbDsR/) and for me, in Chrome 22, it works without the body tag as well.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm not making use of mootools in my code though, so it shouldn't matter. I did add raphael.js as an external resource though, because I didn't know it was available in the framework-dropdown, but that shouldn't matter either.

Comment: @Rajneesh I believe jsfiddle add the JavaScript within the body, and therefor it works in my fiddle, but not in your file. Not sure though.